# String vectors not passing to a class function

Tags: c++, string, vector, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm having some problems  with passing vectors, as parameters, to a  class function. Class is in another file. This is my code:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "class1.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<string> names;

    names.push_back("Bob");
    names.push_back("Gorge");
    names.push_back("Bill");
    names.push_back("Freddy");
    names.push_back("Daniel");
    names.push_back("Emily");


    class1 obj;
    obj.printVector(names);

    system("pause");
}
```

class1.h:

```
#pragma once

class class1
{
public:
    void printVector(std::vector<string>& names);
};
```

class1.cpp:

```
#include <string>

#include "class1.h"

using namespace std;

void class1::printVector(vector<string>& names) {

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << names[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

I tried doing the same thing with other data types (int, char, floats...) and it worked. ALso when i just pass them to a function in main.cpp it works. The errors are:

```
- Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3203   'allocator': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Alloc', expected a real type    tesst   c:\users\...\documents\programs and games\tesst\tesst\class1.h  6

- Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3203   'allocator': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Alloc', expected a real type    tesst   c:\users\...\documents\programs and games\tesst\tesst\class1.h  6

- Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2923   'std::vector': 'string' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'   tesst   c:\users\...\documents\programs and games\tesst\tesst\class1.h  6   

- Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2923   'std::vector': 'string' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'   tesst   c:\users\...\documents\programs and games\tesst\tesst\class1.h  6   

- Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'string': undeclared identifier tesst   c:\users\...\documents\programs and games\tesst\tesst\class1.h  6   

- Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'string': undeclared identifier tesst   c:\users\...\documents\programs and games\tesst\tesst\class1.h  6   

- Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'void class1::printVector(std::vector &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'std::vector &' tesst   c:\users\...\documents\programs and games\tesst\tesst\main.cpp  22  

- Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2511   'void class1::printVector(std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)': overloaded member function not found in 'class1'    tesst   c:\users\...\documents\programs and games\tesst\tesst\class1.cpp    9
```

Please help!
Thank You

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is not with passing parameters to a class.
The following code works here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class class1 {
public:
    void printVector(std::vector<string>& names);

};

void class1::printVector(vector<string>& names) {

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << names[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main() {

    vector<string> names;

    names.push_back("Bob");
    names.push_back("Gorge");
    names.push_back("Bill");
    names.push_back("Freddy");
    names.push_back("Daniel");
    names.push_back("Emily");


    class1 obj;
    obj.printVector(names);
        return 0;
}
```

As mentioned before by Lightness Races in Orbit, your problem is not including vector and string to class1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: I just illustrated that if the problem was passing a vector to a function, the code would break :) but thanks for sharing the link @juanchopanza

Answer (score 1):

class1.h does not include `<string>` or `<vector>.`

You're "getting away with" the former omission by the fact that you just so happen to include `<string>` in your source files before including `class1.h` (not something you should rely on!).

In the latter case, class1.cpp simply has no idea what `vector` means.

**Fix your includes.**

Comment: Nice! I didn't see your answer before submitting mine. This is the more accurate answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow @jose200. You should upvote and accept this answer as it was useful for you :)